# Unable to return view model from view, model properties return just fine

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to web programming and MVC.  I have searched for 2 days now and can not solve this.

- If I try to return a collection of the model class.  In the
  controller I receive an empty collection.
- If I try to return one instance of the model I receive `null` in the
  controller.
- If I try to return a property from the model, everything works as
  expected.

Ideally I would like to return the current "item"

My Model

```
public class Images
{
    private string name; 
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
```

Controller does not work

```
public void Commit(Images inI)
{
    Debug.WriteLine((inI == null).ToString());
}
```

Controller does work

```
public void Commit(string Name)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(Name);
}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<testweb.Models.Images>
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Commit", "Images", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table class="table">
         @foreach (var item in Model)
         {
            <tr>
               <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
               // Does Not work
               <td>@Html.ActionLink("Commit", "Commit", new { inI = item })</td>
               // Does as expected
               <td>@Html.ActionLink("Commit", "Commit", new { Name = item.Name })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate a url based on a models properties, then the usage is

```
@Html.ActionLink("Commit", "Commit", item)
```

since `item` is already an object. Note that the helper generates the route/query string values by using the `.ToString()` method of each property in your model, so this only works if you model contains `string` and value type properties (`int`, `bool` etc). If any properties of the model are complex objects or collections, then binding will fail because it would generate (say) `...&someCollection=System.Collections.Generic[someModel]`. You also need to be cautious using this if the model contains many properties, or the values of the properties are long strings since you could exceed the query string limit and throw an exception.